# Unity Game with Sinatra

Tags: unity-game-engine, sinatra

I am building a Unity game through one of their tutorials to get the feel for Unity and C#. Now I am looking to post it on my portfolio site as something to show, which is on top of a **Sinatra** app. I built the unity game and it gave me the file and the html skeleton, which works fine if I open the html file on my local machine. But when I run my local server, it doesn't want to work and can't find the data file. Does anyone have a solution or is there an alternative to put a unity game on your website?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and easiest ways to host a unity web build that wouldn't be used by a lot of people is actually Dropbox. Just drop the whole build folder in your Dropbox folder, set up privacy accordingly, and link to it from your website. Other than ease of upload, it also gives you a ready-to-use HTTPS, which is required for Facebook canvas, and is a pain to set up otherwise.